# DynamoDB - Conditional put based on number of records

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to achieve a sort of optimistic locking in DynamoDB where I insert a new record based on the number of records that exist with a given partition key (table uses a composite key).

The specific context would be a ledger, where each document in the ledger represents a deposit or withdrawal and contains things like `totalBalance`, `purchasedItem` (null if a deposit), `userId`, `createDate`, etc.

The idea is that the service (async) would fetch the number of ledger entries for a given user as well as their latest record at the beginning of its workflow. It would perform a few operations before updating the ledger.  I'd like the last step to perform a `TransactWrite` where the condition check ensures the same number of ledger entries exists for the user as in the beginning. If not, the process starts over.

I know that DynamoDB supports conditional checks on attributes for a single record, but is it possible to write a condition check that looks at the number of records returned by a query?

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name myLedger --key-condition-expression "userId = :u" --expression-attribute-values '{":u": {"S": "0123abcd"}}' --select "COUNT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.

DynamoDB only operates at the document level and doesn't know how many documents are stored under that partition key. You can't figure it out without reading all of the documents, and there's no guarantee you can even do that in a single operation, let alone in a way that can be used in a condition expression.

Your design of having one document per entry is more appropriate for relational databases, and doesn't really work here. In document databases, you would normally want to have a single document that contains multiple entries.

If you refactor your data model to have all of your entries in a single document, it becomes trivial to perform this update atomically via an update expression.

Comment: I had a suspicion this was the case and have actually already suggested a similar refactor to our lead for this very reason. Thanks for the confirmation!